# Python Pandas Dataframe Challenge #2: Replacing nested iterrows with something better (filter/apply/applymap etc...)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

**Scenario**

I have a nested iterrows statement that works - but I now intend to write better. I'm essentially looking to optimise the processing time.

**Query Context**

1. I need to take a value from the main loop then compare conditions to each row in the whole dataframe
2. Where it finds the same 'JobNumber' one with a 'Task Type' of DP and one LP and it is the first time seeing that JobNumber *then* append details to a new dataframe
3. If it cannot find a partner 'Task Type' row (only one row in the df of type DP or LP) *then* append specific criteria to the new df accordingly
4. Current method uses a nested Iterrows statement and appending 'JobNumber' to a list - then each run: check that list - if not there, check the other conditions.

**Challenges**

1. Getting around nested loops - in this case (dataframes) iterrows
2. Checking a list, as well as df conditions - evaluating
3. appending bespoke details to a NEW dataframe

```
col2 = ['Job Number', 'DP', 'DP Runs', 'LP', 'LP Runs', 'Campaign-level Match' ]
results2_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col2)

for idx, val in results_df.iterrows():
    for idx2, val2 in results_df.iterrows():

        if ((val.loc['Task Type'] == 'DP Task' and val2.loc['Task Type'] == 'LP Task') or (val.loc['Task Type'] == 'LP Task' and val2.loc['Task Type'] == 'DP Task')
            and (val.loc['Job Number'] == val2.loc['Job Number'])) \
                and val.loc['Job Number'] not in temp_list2:
            results2_df = results2_df.append({
                                            'Job Number' : val.loc['Job Number'],
                                            'DP' : 'Yes',
                                            'DP Runs' : val.loc['Run No Ref'],
                                            'LP' : 'Yes',
                                            'LP Runs' : val2.loc['Run No Ref'],
                                            'Campaign-level Match' : 'Yes',
                                        }, ignore_index=True)

            temp_list2.append(val.loc['Job Number'])

    else:
        if val.loc['Task Type'] == 'LP Task' and val.loc['Job Number'] not in temp_list2:
            results2_df = results2_df.append({
                                            'Job Number': val.loc['Job Number'],
                                            'DP' : 'No',
                                            'DP Runs' : 'N/a',
                                            'LP' : 'Yes',
                                            'LP Runs' : val.loc['Run No Ref'],
                                            'Campaign-level Match' : 'LP Only',
                                        }, ignore_index=True)

            temp_list2.append(val.loc['Job Number'])

        elif val.loc['Task Type'] == 'DP Task' and val.loc['Job Number'] not in temp_list2:
            results2_df = results2_df.append({
                                            'Job Number': val.loc['Job Number'],
                                            'DP' : 'Yes',
                                            'DP Runs' : val.loc['Run No Ref'],
                                            'LP' : 'No',
                                            'LP Runs' : 'N/a',
                                            'Campaign-level Match' : 'DP Only',
                                        }, ignore_index=True)

            temp_list2.append(val.loc['Job Number'])


results2_df.to_excel('v2_test_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Sample/Test Dataset**

```
test_df = {'Task Type':["DP Task","LP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","LP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","DP Task","LP Task","DP Task"],
 'Job Number':[643,643,995,698,132,930,566,858,858,119,300,450,131,876,734,734],
'Run No Ref':["Run9, Run8, Run7","Run9, Run8, Run7","Run7, Run6, Run5","Run7, Run6, Run5","Run16, Run15, Run14","Run4, Run3, Run2","Run167, Run166, Run165","Run5, Run4, Run3","Run5, Run4, Run3","Run21, Run20, Run19","Run59, Run58, Run57","Run62, Run61, Run60","Run25, Run24, Run23","Run62, Run61, Run60","Run9, Run8, Run7","Run9, Run8, Run7"]}
results_df = pd.DataFrame(test_df)
```

Would love to learn more about how to solve problems like this as I cannot find anything to specifically address it. (I'm very sure I'm not the only one!)

Thanks in advance all

Comment: You don't have to continually check whether it is the first time you have seen that JobNumber. You can just append them all to the dataframe and then use df.drop_duplicates(subset=['JobNumber''], keep='first') to get rid of the repeats. .

Comment: Good idea - the challenge is on the 1st iteration, 1 matches with 2 - but the 2nd iteration 2 matches with 1 again meaning I end up with dupes in my end dataset. Within the first loop-set I need it to know that its already matched and not check again. Its not something I can filter out before (as I need the data) or afterwards as its too late. Does that make sense?

Comment: why you are getting only `Run9, Run8, Run7` in `LP Runs`  in `results2_df`?

Comment: In this scenario, I've logged the 'last 3 runs' from a previous set - its just test data, but thats why you have those type values